# Masonry js not working with bootstrap tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, masonry

I have created bootstrap tab option and I also apply masonry js. So that box will appear one small and another big.On first tab it is working fine but in another tab it is not working.

My HTML code give below

```
 <ul class="tabs" id="myTab">
      <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">First</li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Second</li>
 </ul>

 <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
 <div class="container">
    <div class="gridnew">
      <div class="grid-item">
        <img src="Result-img-1.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="Result-img-1.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="Result-img-1.jpg" alt="">
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div

 <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content current">
 <div class="container">
     <div class="gridnew">
        <div class="grid-item">
        <img src="Result-img-1.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="Result-img-1.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="Result-img-1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div
```

My JS code Given Below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.gridnew').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item'
  });
```

Comment: trigger .masonry() before you set up the tabs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i got answer.

Trigger .masonry() on every click of my tab.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#myTab li').click(function (e) 
{
     $("[id^='tab']").hide(); 
     e.preventDefault()
     var ids=$(this).data('tab');
     $("#"+ids).show();
     $('.gridnew').masonry({
         itemSelector: '.grid-item'
    });
 })
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

To call 'shown.bs.tab' with no issues use jQuery.noConflict(). For masonry grid, you will need to call 'layout' method.

```
// Create the masonry grid
var $grid = $('.gridnew').masonry({
     itemSelector: '.grid-item',
     fitWidth: true,
     gutter: 0,
     percentPosition: true
});

// Issues with bs tabs and masonry refresh  
jQuery.noConflict();

$(document).on('shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
    // Reload the already created masonry grid, each time you click the Bootstrap tab
    $grid.masonry('layout');
});
```